# Postgresql - invalid input syntax for integer: "x.x"

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using ora2pg. Got this error while COPYing to table.

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "2.8" 
CONTEXT:  COPYsome_table, line 1, column col_err: "2.8"
```

Heres my table:

```
 col1       | bigint                      | NOT NULL
 col2       | timestamp without time zone | NOT NULL
 col_err    | bigint                      |
 col4       | bigint                      |
 col5       | bigint                      |
 col6       | timestamp without time zone |
```

That's line from input file:

```
COPY some_table(col1,col2,col_err,col4,col5,col6) FROM STDIN;
 10      1999-01-01 00:00:00     2.8     2.8     \N      2009-06-14 00:00:00
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does the decimal separator not work here?

Comment: Because the column is an *integer* but the value has a decimal point.

Comment: Because integers don't have decimals. The error message says it all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `DECIMAL` :

```
alter table t alter column col4 type decimal(4,1);
alter table t alter column col5 type decimal(4,1);
```

Change it to the precision you need.

Comment: Thank's. That was really stupid of me. I was hoping ora2pg will convert it correctly. Looks like default NUMBER type was converted to bigint.